# Unable to get a specific properties with @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: spring-boot

I would like to retrieve a property but when a dot is used, I can't, I get null, 
Is there a way to do it still using @ConfigurationProperties ?

See the example:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "prop.foo")
public class Test {
    //This is working
    private String myVal;
    //This is not working
    private String barAnotherVal;

    public void setMyVal(String myVal) {
        this.myVal= myVal;
    }
    public void setBarAnotherVal(String barAnotherVal) {
        this.barAnotherVal= barAnotherVal;
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
prop.foo.myVal
prop.foo.bar.anotherVal
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set `barAnotherVal` on `Test` your property needs to be `prop.foo.barAnotherValue`.

If you want to use `prop.foo.bar.anotherValue` then you need a property for `bar` on `Test`. The `bar` type should then have the `anotherValue` property. Something like this:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "prop.foo")
public class Test {

    private String myVal;

    private Bar bar = new Bar();

    public void setMyVal(String myVal) {
        this.myVal = myVal;

    public Bar getBar() {
        return this.bar;
    }

    public static class Bar {

        private String anotherVal;

        public void setAnotherVal(String anotherVal) {
            this.anotherVal = anotherVal;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Lol yes I exacly tried this without succeed it before my question, but I just noticed I forgot to instantiate the Bar with `new Bar();` !!!! Thx!